# Notifications only work when 'Allow notifications when mirroring or sharing the display' is on

Tags: notifications, ventura

I've checked everywhere and can't find any evidence of my screen being shared or mirrored. However, my notifications only work when the 'Allow notifications when mirroring or sharing the display' setting is enabled. This is a problem because I don't want to receive notifications during meetings when I might be sharing my screen. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can figure out what's causing my Mac to think it's being shared or mirrored?

Ventura 13.1 (22C65)

[image: Version 13.1 (22C65)]

Comment: I'm also experiencing this and finding it a little unsettling. As far as I know my screen is not being mirrored or shared but my Slack notifications are not appearing while this option is toggled to 'Off'. I'm using external displays but I tried with those disconnected and there was no difference. Also Ventura 13.1 (22C65).

Comment: This seems to have corrected itself for me, not sure what changed but I can now turn that toggle off and still get my notifications.

Comment: Jared I've checked and mine has also rectified itself and notifications are working with this toggled off. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to see a list of what programs are "Mirroring or sharing the display"? I assume I have some application that didn't exit properly and possibly a restart would fix this but I'd like to get a list and kill the app in question instead.

Answer (score 0):

@JoshStrange You can go to System Settings->Privacy & Security->Screen Recording & System Audio and any apps that have been enabled for Screen Recording/Sharing will be listed there.

In my case my notification Alerts were being demoted to Banners even when I wasn't deliberately sharing my screen via Zoom or anything else, because I'm using a MacBook Air and two external displays - my dock uses Silicon Motion's MacOS InstantView software to emulate the second external display which does that by leveraging - you guessed it - ScreenSharing.